# Source Format and decomposed files of object translation

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata, customobjecttranslation

Sfdx decomposes objectTranslation metadata files into multiple sub-files as highlighted [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_source_file_format.htm). That page mentions that metadata format file is split into three files.

1. <field_name>.fieldTranslation-meta.xml
2. <object_name>.objectTranslation-meta.xml
3. <object_translation>.objectTranslation-meta.xml

I have seen examples of #1 and #3 (for ex., [here](https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/NPSP/tree/main/force-app/main/default/objectTranslations/Account-es)) but haven't seen any examples of #2. The documentation is very sparse in that regard to state which fields from [CustomObjectTranslation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_customobjecttranslation.htm) goes into file file format#2.

Do you know what is the difference between #2 and #3 and have any public examples of #2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, wording is quite confusing in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_source_file_format.htm). As per my understanding:

1. `<field_name>.fieldTranslation-meta.xml`

   - This represents the translation of field label for a specific language.
2. `<object_name>.objectTranslation-meta.xml`

   - This represents the translation of object label for a specific language.
3. `<object_translation>.objectTranslation-meta.xml`

   - [Project Structure documentations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_source_file_format.htm) says:

     > The remaining pieces of the custom object translation are placed in a file called `<objectTranslation>.objectTranslation-meta.xml`.
   - I think, here what they intent to say is: `<object_translation>` represents the the actual folder inside the [`objectTranslations`](https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/NPSP/tree/main/force-app/main/default/objectTranslations) folder for individual language.

---

Based on above theory, I'd categorize them as below:

[image]

---

Note: I'd let others correct me in case this is incorrect :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't think documentation says that or means as they include file extn in #2 (.objectTranslation-meta.xml) but considering lack of information and examples, we will have to assume this.